# nginx routing with django

Tags: django, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm a bit stuck on how to accomplish the setup I want.  Putting aside whether it's a good idea, I am trying to setup a development/test and production django application on the same server under the same domain.  I am using nginx as the public-facing server, which then should send requests to the appropriate application server based on whether the url starts with the `/dev/` prefix.  However, I cannot get the nginx configuration quite right.

Ideally, requests to `http://example.com/admin` go to the production app, and `http://example.com/dev/admin` goes to the dev version.  This way, the django `urls.py` is the same for both, such as:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ... other paths ...
]
```

The django apps are in docker containers, which communicate with the host machine via unix sockets.  That is, I start the docker container with something like:

`docker run -v /www:/host_dir me/mydocker`

and in that container, the entrypoint command is:

`gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application --bind=unix:/host_dir/xyz.sock`

My nginx conf on the host machine looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name 35.231.70.176;

    location /dev {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/www/dev.sock:;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/www/production.sock:;
    }
}
```

In this configuration, I get the following:

`http://example.com/admin` works as expected

`http://example.com/dev/admin` goes to the PRODUCTION admin site.

In addition to the location block above, I have tried several variants in the nginx conf (keeping the `location / {...}` block the same as above), including:

1. Add slash to location:

   ```
   location /dev/ {
       include proxy_params;
       proxy_pass http://unix:/www/dev.sock:;
   }
   ```
2. Add slash to proxy_pass:

   ```
   location /dev {
       include proxy_params;
       proxy_pass http://unix:/www/dev.sock:/;
   }
   ```
3. Add slash to both location and proxy pass:

   ```
   location /dev/ {
       include proxy_params;
       proxy_pass http://unix:/www/dev.sock:/;
   }
   ```

ALL of these variants end up sending `http://example.com/dev/admin` to the production application, so I'm confused.  I thought that since it first matches the `/dev` block, it should send the request to the dev application, but clearly I'm not understanding.

Comment: What happens if you kill the production gunicorn process, and try to reload the /dev/admin URL (preferably with Firefox's cache disabled)?

Comment: If I do that, I get the following reports from django's debug page (it's trying to match `admin/`):

(Sorry about formatting in the comment box)
case 0 (part of full nginx conf shown above):  
The current path, dev/admin/, didn't match any of these
----
case 1:
The current path, dev/admin/, didn't match any of these.
----
case 2:
The current path, /admin/, didn't match any of these.
----
case 3:
502 bad gateway, so attempting to get to production server, which is down

Comment: I'd try to add `try_files $uri /index.html`... also don't you need to `include uwsgi_params` I never used gunicorn. It could be that the proxy_params you have does that...

Comment: Ok, I took a look on gunicorn and I feel like you have misconfigured the supervisor/conf.d. You have to create two separate applications and each of their paths there and create two *.conf files for each of them. Take a look here http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/10/29/serving-multiple-django-applications-with-nginx-gunicorn-supervisor/

Comment: I don't have supervisor managing any of my applications (I didn't install it in the containers).  It seems like that article has a slightly different setup, which is not quite what I am after.

I think the comment above about shutting down the production server was helpful in diagnosis.  With the production server removed, my question reduces down to "how can requests to `http://example.com/dev/admin/` end up correctly at the `admin/` url in the django app?".  The requests are clearly reaching gunicorn, but the url that django receives is always just a bit off.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12991235/2052575) may help you, which links to [This blog](http://archive.is/DJ9Hr) for more info.  I think you need to set `proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /dev;` in your `location /dev` block.